# Java unexpected keys in HashMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use HashMap by putting some key-value pair (very very basic). But I am facing a weird issue. The key that I am putting there is not visible when I iterate over it rather it creates the key with the **class name**. Here is the code snippet:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Command> allCommands(Command command1, Command command2) {
        Map<String, Command> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("first", command1);
        map.put("second", command2);
        return map;
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, RouterStrategy> allStrategies(KafkaRouter kafkaRouter) {
        Map<String, RouterStrategy> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("kafka", kafkaRouter);

        return map;
    }
}
```

The class which is using this bean:

```
@Service
public class Postman {

    private Map<String, RouterStrategy> allStrategies;

    @Autowired
    public Postman(Map<String, RouterStrategy> allStrategies) {
        this.allStrategies = allStrategies;
    }

    public void process(String strategy,Envelope envelope) throws Exception{
        allStrategies.forEach((k,v) -> logger.info(k + " -> " + v));
        RouterStrategy routerStrategy = allStrategies.get(strategy);
        routerStrategy.routeMessage(envelope);
    }
}
```

The method which calls this process() method is as below:

```
public class SomeCommand implements Command {


    Postman postman;
    
    public SomeCommand(Postman postman) {
        this.postman = postman;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void execute(Envelope envelope) throws Exception {
        postman.process("kafka",envelope);
    }

}
```

Now, the problem here is if I run the code, process() method of the Postman class should print the strategy map with *"kafka"* as one of the keys. But it prints below output-

```
applog.msg=kafkaRouter -> KafkaRouter{kafkaTemplate=org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate@79708}
```

Pretty weird, whatever the key I am setting is simply ignored rather it creates this Map by using characters of the class name `(KafkaRouter -> kafkaRouter)`. This thing is same if I add an additional key-value pair in the strategy map. For example, if I modify the strategy map like mentioned below-

```
@Bean
    public Map<String, RouterStrategy> allStrategies(KafkaRouter kafkaRouter, RestRouter restRouter) {
        Map<String, RouterStrategy> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("kafka", kafkaRouter);
        map.put("rest", restRouter);
        return map;

    }
```

Strategy interface-

```
public interface RouterStrategy {
    void routeMessage(Envelope envelope) throws Exception;
}
```

Strategy implementation-

```
@Service
public class KafkaRouter implements RouterStrategy{

    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaRouter(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void routeMessage(Envelope envelope) throws Exception {
        // Logic to get additional details like Kafka topic name, etc.

        sendMessage(envelope.getContent());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "KafkaRouter{" +
                "kafkaTemplate=" + kafkaTemplate + '}';
    }

    // Kafka publisher logic
    private void sendMessage(String content) throws Exception {
        
    }
}
```

In this case, two keys are printed `kafkaRouter` and `restRouter`. Since it can't "find the key", it throws NullPointerException. Anything I am missing? TIA

Other details:

- Springboot version - 2.3.10.RELEASE
- JDK - OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.40+15-NV (build 11.0.7.0.101+5-LTS)

Comment: Where are you actually calling your bean's `allStrategies` method?  I can't see it.

Comment: allStrategies bean is a part of @Configuration class which I did not mention here. I am injecting this bean into the Postman class.

Comment: this is weird, is it possible to share your full code?

Comment: I will share the missing class and interface. Hope it will help to resolve this. The full code is actually on our internal GitHub server.

Comment: Try to add qualifier in `allStrategies` bean initialization and then use it on autowiring.

Comment: @Alex- I don't know how but adding the Qualifier worked. In my opinion, I have another bean in Configuration class that returns Map of a totally different key-value combination. Maybe that confused the bootstrap process while initializing the beans which return Map of some kind.  Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.